# NLP Phrase Search in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, whoosh

I have been going through many Libraries like whoosh/nltk and concepts like word net.

However I am unable to tackle my problem. I am not sure if I can find a library for this or I have to build this using the above mentioned resources.

**Question:**
My scenario is that I have to search for key words. 
Say I have key words like 'Sales Document' / 'Purchase Documents' and have to search for them in a small 10-15 pages book.

**The catch is:** 
Now they can also be written as 'Sales should be documented' or 'company selling should be written in the text files'. (For Sales Document - Keyword) Is there an approach here or will I have to build something?

The code for the POS Tags is as follows. If no library is available I will have to proceed with this.

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from pandas import Series
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def tag(x):
    return pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))



synonyms = []
antonyms = []

for syn in wordnet.synsets("Sales document"):
    #print("Down2")
    print (syn)
    #print("Down")
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        print(" \n")
        print(l)
        synonyms.append(l.name())
        if l.antonyms():
            antonyms.append(l.antonyms()[0].name())

print(set(synonyms))
print(set(antonyms))

for i in synonyms:
    print(tag(i))
```

**Update:**
We went ahead and made a python program - Feel free to fork it. (Pun intended) 
Further the Git Dhund is very untidy right now will clean it once completed. 
Currently it is still in a development phase.

The is the [link](https://github.com/shivam1104/Dhund).

Comment: I'm going to vote this as off-topic since you haven't shown an attempt. I'm happy to retract the close vote if you post something that shows you've tried.

Comment: @erip Sometimes you just don't know what you don't know! I like SO's ability to give a direction, even if there isn't a clear answer.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a readily available library or do I proceed with building my own repository for this requirement using the POS Tags.

Comment: This kind of indexing is built into SOLR.  You can search by token proximity.

Answer (score 2):

To match occurrences like **"Sales should be documented"**, this can be done by increasing the `slop` parameter in the Phrase query object of Whoosh.

> whoosh.query.Phrase(fieldname, words, slop=1, boost=1.0, char_ranges=None)
>   slop – the number of words allowed between each “word” in the phrase; the default of 1 means the phrase must match exactly.

You can also define slop in Query like this: `"Sales should be documented"~5`

---

To match the second example **"company selling should be written in the text files"**, this needs a semantic processing for your texts. Whoosh has a low-level implementation for [wordnet thesaurus](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/lang/wordnet.html) to allow you index synonyms but it has only one-word synonyms.